# How to change UTf8_STRING encoding to Printable_STRING in bouncy castle

Tags: windows-phone-8, x509certificate, bouncycastle

We are implementing Windows MDM. In this,we we generate `X509Certificate` device certificate from `PKCS#10` CSR(obtained from device in previuos request) using BC library.

Now problem is subject property of device cert has `UTF8_STRING` encoding and I want to override it to `PRINTABLE_STRING`.

I need to override behavior of BC library to use `ASN.1 type: PRINTABLE_STRING`.
But I am not getting way to do it.

Comment: Hey facing same issues here. did u find any wayout ?

Comment: Any updated to this question?